# outlook 2010 - warning popup before sending email from personal mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I've outlook 2010 at my work and linked my personal mail id as a primary account and the rest of the group shared mail id are linked at server level.

So when I send a new email from the group, it selects the personal mail id by default and user have to change it everytime.

I use the below macro to provide a warning pop up when the `From` is selected as my personal id however this macro warn even if the shared mail id is selected in `From`.

How to prevent this from warning if the `From` is not the primary id or personal id or is there a macro to automatically select the `From` when a new email is created based on the group shared mail id's?

---

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
If InStr(LCase(Item.SendUsingAccount), "sara@example.com.") Then
    Prompt$ = "You sending this from sara@example.com. Are you sure you want to send it?"
    If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From corresponds to the SentOnBehalfOfName property. This is empty until mail is sent, unless you set it in code before sending. Not useful here as you want to verify if you forgot to set it.

```
Private Sub SetFrom()

Dim curritem As mailItem
Dim uPrompt As String

Set curritem = CreateItem(olMailItem)

curritem.Display

uPrompt = "This mail has not been sent." & vbCr & vbCr
uPrompt = uPrompt & "The SentOnBehalfOfName (From) property is empty unless set in the code." & vbCr & vbCr
uPrompt = uPrompt & "See between the quotes." & vbCr & vbCr
MsgBox uPrompt & Chr(34) & ActiveInspector.currentItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & Chr(34)

' Note: The From in the user interface does not populate the property."

curritem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sharedmailbox@example.com"

' For demonstration purposes. Not necessary to display in real code.
curritem.Close olSave
curritem.Display

MsgBox "SentOnBehalfOfName set in the code." & vbCr & vbCr & _
    "The SentOnBehalfOfName (From) is set to: " & curritem.SentOnBehalfOfName

ExitRoutine:
    Set curritem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Your attempt to verify SendUsingAccount has likely failed due to having one account with many mailboxes where you want many accounts.

```
Sub Account_name()

Dim olAcct As account
Dim countAcc As Long
Dim i As Long

countAcc = Session.Accounts.count

For i = 1 To countAcc
    Debug.Print "Account.....: " & i
    Debug.Print " DisplayName: " & Session.Accounts.Item(i).DisplayName
    Debug.Print " UserName   : " & Session.Accounts.Item(i).userName
    Debug.Print
Next

End Sub
```

If you find you have only one account see [Add an email account to Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b) to to add accounts if you have the required permissions.